# How to show dropdown configurable attribute in Product Category View in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute, configurable-swatches

I have **color** attribute of type **visual swatch**, which is displayed on **category view** as well as **catalog search view** below the product images, on selecting the swatches, it changed the image as well price. But when I change this color attribute to type **dropdown**, I am not able to see the same on category and search view. Is there any configuration from the Admin panel to make it appear on the category views? If not, then can someone please guide on how to write custom code for it?